# Search and term variables by character string

Tags: r, variables, character

I have a maybe simple problem, but I can't solve it. 
I have two list's. List A is empty and a list B has several named columns. Now, I want to select a colum of B by a variable and put it in list A. Somehow like shown in the example:

```
A<-list()
B<-list()
VAR<-"a"

B$a<-c(1:10)
B$b<-c(10:20)
B$c<-c(20:30)

#This of course dosn't work...
A$VAR<-B$VAR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract list entry with `B[[VAR]]` and append new entry to a list using [`get`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/get) (`A[[get("VAR")]] <- newEntry`):

```
A[[get("VAR")]] <- B[[VAR]]

## A list
# $a
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: Hey that works. Thank you for answering this easy question.

Comment: @lupasch happy to help, you can accept my solution if it solved your problem